# What's the status of dlopen for Mac apps?

Tags: dlopen, dyld

In WWDC talks, Apple devs have mentioned that they want to move away from `dlopen` with the introduction of `dyld3`. What's the status of `dlopen`, at present and for the future? Does it have limitations with `dyld3`?